# Object is possibly 'undefined' after null check

Tags: typescript

I'm getting

> Variable 'layer' is used before being assigned.

here: `if(layer == null || layer == undefined){`

```
public static myFunc(type: number) {
    var layer: VectorLayer;
    if (type === 1) {
        layer = Map.getStaticVariableOne();
    } else if (type === 2) {
        layer = Map.getStaticVariableTwo();
    }
    if(layer == null || layer == undefined){
        return;
    }
    Utils.doThings(layer);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong in Typescript?

Comment: btw, `layer == null` covers `layer == undefined`

Comment: can you please explain what is your error is?

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate that exact error with the code presented, but my solution below should work.  What version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: Please consider editing the code in your question to constitute a [mcve] as described in the guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  The code should be something anyone can drop into an IDE and the only problem should be the one you're facing.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz sorry, I'm a beginner of typescript and stackoverflow too! Next time I'll make the test code better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quirk of TypeScript.

To get around this for now, you can perform a "typecast" to tell the compiler that `layer` is not undefined when you use it.

```
Utils.doThings(<VectorLayer> layer);

// alternatively
// Utils.doThings(layer as VectorLayer);
```

Alternatively, you could do something like the following ([tested](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBLAdgFxDAZlMCBq4qA9jADJQCeG8A3gL4DcAUKJLAmwM6fwCqqiCDxrxOqKALDxgRACoALFAHNOACmhUYALngEwxMpQwBKHQDciiYPEYtw0OPC49ZIMQFkoAB1pN4-0XFJeCUQVABlIMQwPFhEKAAjCBAAeWQQVVNdQhJyTWYAwIlokLDI4pi4xOTZAHciTJ09AzyMZjomJmd4VzFfQq8AVySSsQr4AFsKADFB5DBVVAovEB1kQYmEk37CgLNYeA0MJpzDTXgAH3g50EwUEGsAXmvkW-vgAt3-Py+kTHhFssEI8QfAAIzGHa-AJHGDwZ69VCeLwAOlCESilRg8SSqXSmU+Xzo8BAQgQiH+gJW8NBACZITQftD-LD4T03EjvGiypjYtjqiA6g1jITdh0mbsKQDWSDnusIBBLlcZaCbiA7ulgMZGcyAnBUIMYMhRYVxdD+IJOCiZAplGpYSKJR06EA)):

```
public static myFunc(type: number) {
    var layer: VectorLayer | undefined = undefined;

    if (type === 1) {
        layer = TestMap.getStaticVariableOne();
    } else if (type === 2) {
        layer = TestMap.getStaticVariableTwo();
    }

    if (layer === null || layer === undefined){
        return;
    }

    Utils.doThings(layer);
}
```

The major difference is that you specify that layer can be `undefined` and you explicitly set it to `undefined`.  Then you just check to make sure it's not undefined before you use it.

Comment: Adding the "| undefined" solved the problem. Thank you c1moore, I'm sorry but I'm a beginner of typescript.

Comment: Saved my life. The second suggestion resolved an issue I was having getting an "Object is possibly undefined" inside a null/undefined check. Assigning it the undefined union fixed the issue so that it correctly identified the reference was inside the null check

Answer (score 1):

Just check if `layer` exists:

```
if (!layer) {
  return;
}
Utils.doThings(layer);
```

To check a bit more verbose and not only against truthy values:

```
if (layer === undefined || layer === null) { // Or just layer == null
  return;
}
Utils.doThings(layer);
```

Comment: What if `layer` is an empty string, or the number `0`, or another falsey (but defined) value?

Comment: @spender Well, you are right - I am still learning TS :) I thought, since `var layer: VectorLayer;` it's enough to check against `!layer`.

Comment: Ah. My bad. I didn't see it defined as an object type... probably (although pedantically, you could `type VectorLayer = number; const x:VectorLayer  = 0;` )

Comment: I could not check if 'layer' was undefined or null because the type was VectorLayer and the if\else if did not guarantee that variable was assigned. The error was `Variable 'layer' is used before being assigned.`